# PHP get method ajax url reading

Tags: php

i have like this url the

> site.com/#request/values-1
>
> site.com/#request/values-2

how can i take this URL? with php  what are u think this about?

```
$request = ?
```

Comment: Your doubt is not clear. Kindly provide more description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: You need to use javascript to achieve that.

```
<script language = "javascript">

var query = location.href.split('#');

var anchorValueSplit = query[1].split("/");

var anchorValue = anchorValueSplit[1];

alert(anchorValue);

</script>
```

EDIT:Another solution

```
<script language = "javascript">

if(location.href.indexOf("#") > 0) {

    location.href = location.href.replace("#","?");

}

</script>
<?php

$param = array_keys($_GET);
$param = $param[0];

$breakParam = explode("/",$param);

echo $request = $breakParam[1];


?>
```

Comment: " Notice: Undefined index: PATH_INFO  " i am taking this error . PATH_INFO not defined in php?

Comment: Oh i am sorry. I didnt test it. Basically you can get the string after the "#" tag, because php cannot read that. It is client sided. You need to use javascript to achieve that.

Comment: i didint seem giving full url string in php
i tested $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']  but its giving error if there are any way taking full string sharing me pls

Comment: I got your point. a quick google search reveals that setting cgi.fix_pathinfo=0 in php.ini should fix the error. But its still not the solution to your problem. Is it fine if you rewrite your url through javascript to make it like site.com?request/values-1 ? If yes then i have a solution for you.

Comment: No way getting in php full path? so i tried  cg.fix_pathinfo=1 also not define php PATH_INFO varriables

Comment: I am afraid. But i think no. I am making one more edit. Check if it helps.